# How to add additional IConfigurationProvider to console app?

Tags: c#, console-application, appsettings

I'm working on a console application where I'm trying to read the settings from "appsettings.Development.json".

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
        var mySettingsSection = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("MyAppSettings");
```

`mySettingsSection` has a value in `Key` and `Path`, but not in `Value`. When I take a look at `hostContext.Configuration`, I see that I only have four providers, which does not include one for "appsettings.Development.json". Even after renaming my settings to "appsettings.json" to match the third provider in the `Providers` list, I am unable to get the values.

[image]

I have changed the "Build action" to "Content" and "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always"

When I use similar code in my web application, I get more providers, including one for "appsettings.Development.json"

[image]

The `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` that I'm using in my console application claims to load more providers than what I'm getting.
[image]

The console project does include "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting".

Answer (score 1):

in console app you can add other provider manually like the below code:

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
         {
             config.Sources.Clear();
             config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
             config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
             config.AddXmlFile("app.config", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

         })
         .UseConsoleLifetime();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to add it manually considering that `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` says it will load "appsettings.json" and "appsettings.[EnvironmentName].json"

Comment: in console application you use generic host instead of using web host so in web host we have Appsetting.json

Comment: I agree. But if you look at the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` remarks (the last screenshot), you see that it claims that it adds several app `IConfiguration`, so I would expect that I did not have to add them manually.

Comment: ok can you send me the link of that snapshot?

Comment: It's in the initial question, but here it is again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd9fd.png

Comment: yeah i have already seen it. i mean that can you send me the link of that website which you have gotten this snap shot. I mean that to check weather it is a valid source or not?

Comment: The screenshots I included in the question are from breakpoints in my running code.